# how to alter an existing table column in laravel 5.3 using migrations

Tags: php, laravel-5, doctrine-orm

I have this:

> $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();

But I want to change it to this:

> $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable()->default(3);

I had wanted to use this, but the source syntax I could not understand:

> php artisan make:migration update_role_id_in_users --table=users

I even tried using `doctrine/ddbal` package and running this:

> php artisan make:migration modify_role_id_in_users --table=users

with the migration set up like this:

```
class ModifyRoleIdInUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable()->default(3)->change();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
}
```

**But I get this error when I go migrate:**

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'users_role_id_index'
>   (SQL: alter table 'users' add index 'users_role_id_index'('role_
>   id'))
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'users_role_id_index'
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1061 Duplicate key name 'users_role_id_index'

How can I alter the `column` without doing a `migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`change()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns) method to do this:

```
$table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable()->default(3)->change();
```

> Remember to run `composer require doctrine/dbal` before updating your
>   columns via migrations

Hope this helps!

Comment: please is that code to be added to the `original user migration` or the `modify migration code` as I have done above.

Comment: You will need to create a new migration and then put this code into that migration

Comment: I tried as you can see at the top but it failed. I solved it by simply adding `->default(3)->change()` to the `user migration` and I `ran php artisan migrate` and it changed the column and its ok now.

Comment: I don't know why its giving you the error but I think the `change()` method works for you! :D

Comment: it works if put in the `user migration` not creating a new migration.

Comment: But you should not edit the migration as its the bad practice, if you want a change at any time you should create a new migration to make your desired change!

Comment: that how I was taught but in this case i tried that it gave that error so when I tried the one I used to solve it, it went well. And please note I am using `laravel 5.3` perhaps this is the way its now done. Not an expert...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to:

1. run composer require doctrine/ddbal
2. add the changes I wanted `default(3)` to the end of the `role_id column` like this `$table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable()->default(3)->change();`
3. The run `php artisan migrate`

And that solved it and the table was altered.